# Java constructor chaining with method reference

Tags: java

I've encountered a situation that looked more or less like this while refactoring code; rewritten here for the sake of the example:

```
public class UrlProbe {
    private final OkHttpClient http;
    private final String url;
    private final Function<Response, Object> transform;
    private Object cachedValue;

    public UrlProbe(OkHttpClient http, String url) {
        this(http, url, this::debuggingStringTransform);
    }

    public UrlProbe(OkHttpClient http, String url, Function<Response, Object> transform) {
        this.http = http;
        this.url = url;
        this.transform = transform;
    }

    private Object debuggingStringTransform(Response response) {
        String newValue = response.body().toString();
        System.out.println("Debugging new value from url " + url + ": " + newValue);
        return newValue;
    }

    public synchronized Object probe() {
        if (cachedValue != null) {
            return cachedValue;
        }

        try (Response response = http.newCall(new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build()).execute()) {
            cachedValue = transform.apply(response);
            return cachedValue;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will not compile because we `cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called`:

```
public UrlProbe(OkHttpClient http, String url) {
    this(http, url, this::debuggingStringTransform);
}
```

The following will not compile either:

```
public UrlProbe(OkHttpClient http, String url) {
    this(http, url, response -> debuggingStringTransform(response));
}
```

The only way I've found around this is to explicitly use a non-chaining constructor:

```
public UrlProbe(OkHttpClient http, String url) {
    this.http = http;
    this.url = url;
    this.transform = this::debuggingStringTransform;
}
```

While it makes sense to restrict the use of `this` in constructors chaining arguments, I find it surprising in this particular context as there doesn't appear to be any kind of evaluation of the object being constructed caused by the use of `this` when it comes to method references and the contents of a lambda expression.

Is there a rationale behind this restriction other than it is because JLS §8.8.7.1 says so?

Comment: you can also make method `debuggingStringTransform` static and use static method reference

Comment: @VladBochenin The situation I've encountered at work was a little more complex than this, but in my example `debuggingStringTransform` I took care to include a reference to the instance field `url` so that it can't be static

Comment: It's because you cannot guarantee that debugginStringTransform is not called before this or super is called. What if the next constructor calls the function before executing super?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing referencing this scope that early would break code that looks like this

```
public class UrlProbe {
    final String url;
    final String param2;
    public UrlProbe(String url) {
        this(url, this::debuggingStringTransform);
    }

    public UrlProbe(String url, Function<String, String> transform) {
        this(url, transform.apply("")); // <-- What should happen when url is referenced here?

    }
    public UrlProbe(String url, String param2) {
        this.url = url;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    private String debuggingStringTransform(String response) {
        System.out.println("Debugging new value from url " + url + ": " + response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

That's at least one way of violating the rules.

Comment: This is interesting, it absolutely did not occur to me that the constructor being called could invoke the function that was passed as a parameter (and possibly chain it to another constructor).

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ shows this on the tooltip for why this code is "bad":

[image]

> Cannot reference 'this' before supertype constructor has been called

This makes sense.  You're in the middle of constructing your object and the method reference as defined only exists *after* the class is instantiated.  It *can't* realistically exist *before* it's fully instantiated, since from a semantic standpoint, you can't actually do anything with it until it's "ready".

If you wanted to get around this, you *could* change that function to a static one, since there's no state required for it:

```
public UrlProbe(OkHttpClient http, String url) {
    this(http, url, UrlProbe::debuggingStringTransform);
}

private static Object debuggingStringTransform(Response response) {
    String newValue = response.body().toString();
    System.out.println("Debugging new value from url " + url + ": " + newValue);
    return newValue;
}
```

...although admittedly it looks *weird* to see a `private static` method.

Alternatively, have this function exist *elsewhere* in the same package, like in a static class at the bottom of this one:

```
public UrlProbe(OkHttpClient http, String url) {
    this(http, url, Functions::debuggingStringTransform);
}

static class Functions {
    static Object debuggingStringTransform(Response response) {
        String newValue = response.body().toString();
        System.out.println("Debugging new value from url " + url + ": " + newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
}
```